# How to use git remote add to push to an other computer?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to push some code a remote server so I created a new remote:

`git remote add server ssh://nic@somehost.com/home/nic/workplace/project`

I confirmed that everything is the way it supposed to be using: `git remote -v`

I then proceed to try to push it but I get an error:

```
[nic:15:48@project/]%git push -u server --all
nic@somehost.com's password: 
zsh:1: command not found: git-receive-pack
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
zsh: exit 128   git push -u server --all
```

I can SSH just fine to the host using `ssh nic@somehost.com` and I can navigate to the folder and create a file there so the permissions are correct. I've searched the web and I can't find what's wrong. Maybe a Git hacker will see my stupid mistake in a second. I've tried various format for the remote address but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The problem is in the error message: `zsh` (the shell obtained when logging in on that machine) cannot find the command `git-receive-pack`, which is what Git needs that machine to run in order to receive pushed data. However it is that you teach zsh to look for `git-receive-pack` (setting `$PATH` if it's like most other shells), you will have to do that; or install Git if it's not actually installed there.

Comment: Thanks torek, I tried that but it finds when I ssh to the host... `%git-receive-pack
usage: git receive-pack <git-dir>` maybe it's not picking the right shell? zsh it the shell that I use though.

Comment: Maybe you're adjusting `$PATH` when logging in interactively, but not when not-interactive. What happens if you run, e.g., `ssh <host> which git-receive-pack` (non-interactive command)?

Comment: hum that's interesting I get `git-receive-pack not found`. I guess it's not loading my `.zshrc`. That's probably the issue. I'll look at a way to fix that :) I didn't know that interactive SSH was any different.

Comment: All shells get some indication at startup as to whether they are being run interactively (should print prompts and read commands) or not (should run a specified command). Most shell startup scripts should take care not to produce output when run non-interactively, since a program (like Git!) might be expecting some particular output from the other program they are running, and not any shell-produced text. So most startup scripts include something like: `if we_are_interactive; then ...; fi` or `if not_interactive; then exit; fi` - which should be done *after* any master `$PATH` adjustment!

Comment: So yes zsh has different files depending on what mode you use: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html I created a .zshenv that loads the right path for my non-interactive session. Sourcing my .zshrc didn't work so there is probably a nested source file that has a if like that. I need to spend some time digging. Thank you so much for your help. You are the hero of my day! Make your comment a response and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Well, without the zsh specific part, it's still not the answer ... but I don't use zsh so I'm not sure what bells and whistles it has!